# How do I use module aliases in Serverless Stack?

Tags: material-ui, serverless-framework, esbuild

I am trying to follow the guide for Material UI on replacing the existing style engine with styled-components https://mui.com/guides/styled-engine/

I am also using it as part of the Serverless Stack framework which shows that it is using ESBuild https://docs.serverless-stack.com/packages/cli#build

Is it possible to do this module aliasing? I looked around but wasn't able to figure out how.

Answer (score 0):

After checking on their slack, I figured out that ESBuild is only used in building the backend SST.Functions. But in the material-ui examples, there is an example on how to do the aliasing for create-react-app https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/next/examples/create-react-app-with-styled-components-typescript.